# Delete from another table when deleting with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I have a problem when I'm trying to delete some information in my schema with foreign keys.
Here are my Tables

```
CREATE TABLE tb_class (class_ID INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE tb_product (fingerprint VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE tb_class_product (class_ID INT,
fingerprint VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (class_ID, fingerprint),
UNIQUE INDEX tb_class_product_UNIQUE (fingerprint ASC),
FOREIGN KEY (class_ID) REFERENCES tb_class(class_ID)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (fingerprint) REFERENCES tb_product(fingerprint)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

When i delete a *class_ID* in **tb_class**, I want that the information in **tb_class_product** AND the *fingerprint* in **tb_product** are automatically deleted.

I have already tried to add the following Trigger to **tb_class_product**, but without success

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tb_class_product_after_delete
AFTER DELETE ON tb_class_product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tb_product WHERE tb_product.fingerprint=old.fingerprint;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

--------EDIT--------
Ok. I figured out that the cascade foreign key only delete foreign key entrys when the primary key is deleted, but it doesn't delete the primary key when the foreign key is deleted.

Besides, i have found that when a cascade foreign key is deleted, the trigger doesn't operate.

Now i have found a solution that works for me.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_class (class_ID INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE tb_product (fingerprint VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE tb_class_product (class_ID INT,
fingerprint VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (class_ID, fingerprint),
UNIQUE INDEX tb_class_product_UNIQUE (fingerprint ASC),
FOREIGN KEY (class_ID) REFERENCES tb_class(class_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (fingerprint) REFERENCES tb_product(fingerprint));

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tb_class_product_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON tb_class_product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF @deleting_from_product IS NULL THEN
        SET @deleting_from_class_product=1;
        DELETE FROM tb_product WHERE tb_product.fingerprint=old.fingerprint;
        SET @deleting_from_class_product=NULL;
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tb_class_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE tb_class FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tb_class_product WHERE tb_class_product.class_ID=old.class_ID;
END; //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tb_product_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE tb_product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF @deleting_from_class_product IS NULL THEN
        SET @deleting_from_product=1;
        DELETE FROM tb_class_product WHERE tb_class_product.fingerprint=old.fingerprint:
        SET @deleting_from_product=NULL;
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `tb_class_product` doesn't have any information regarding `tb_class`

Answer (score 0):

With the indexes declared in the way you have described, the data should be automatically deleted from the other tables.
Could you please give the mysql version you are using, and the say what is the effect of the delete - does it throw an error?

Comment: I'm using mySQL Version 5.7 and the delte returns no error.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error, and does not delete all related records, just the one record indiceted in the delete statement? From which table you are deleting?